# How to get the cost history when using fminunc in matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, data-visualization

I there any way I can get the the cost history or the values that my cost function returns to fminunc at each iteration in matlab? I would like to use it to plot a cost vs iteration graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you read the [help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/fminunc.html#f854831) file as it there is a lot you can do with fminunc options. If you're specifically interested in plotting the cost, it can do that for you automatically:

```
options = optimset('PlotFcns', @optimplotfval);
x = fminunc(fun,x0,options)
```